# force compiler to refresh variable content in specific point

Tags: c, thread-safety, volatile

I have a global variable that in most time can't be changed by other thread, but in single point it can.

I want to force the compiler to refresh the registers that holding this global content after that point, but without defining this global to be volatile all the time because it time consuming.

Comment: Never do unprotected multi-threaded access to a variable. That leads to data-races and undefined behavior. And generally, global variables should be avoided.

Comment: It is protected global, hut in one point in the middle other thread can access it and in this time point current thread is not accessing it

Comment: As you want some constraint on accesses, it will necessarily consume time to enforce the semantic. You may need to look at memory ordering mechanisms. Looks like you need a release-consume policy.

Comment: Do you realize that this is the _**textbook example**_ of wanting to "both keep your pie and eat it"?

Answer (score 2):

Since the global variable is shared and can potentially be modified by more than one thread, it should be declared `volatile`. It may then be copied to and from a non-volatile variable if it needs to be used for lengthy local processing.

Even if there is currently a way to "fool" the compiler into forcing a true read/write of the variable without declaring it volatile, chances are that at some point compiler optimizers will get even smarter and optimize that construct away.

Answer (score 0):

You can call some dummy function from other file after this point, that will force the compiler to refresh the global because he can't know if the global changed in the dummy function. It is bit not nice code but it will work.

Comment: How exactly is allowing some dummy function calling overhead more efficient than declaring a variable volatile though? I don't understand your reasoning here.

Comment: The dummy function calls forces a refresh at that particular point, marking the variable volatile forces a refresh whenever the object is accessed. If you only need it refreshed at one spot the call to external function makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Nice try, but it will not work. The dummy function would have to be invoked at every place where the variable is read. The OP is asking for some magic trick to do at the one point where the variable is written.  Which cannot be done.